# Is there any way of knowing (via code) if a user is in the app and using it right now?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to incorporate a feature into one of my apps that allows you to message users that are, at that moment, in and using the app. I've searched for a while now, but with no luck finding any article, API, npm package, etc, that supports this concept - if it even is possible.

I'd rather use an API than see when the user was last on the app via a timestamp and then "guess" if the user is still using the app.

I'm using React Native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that AppState equals to 'active'.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate